# How to save Firebase Device Token in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, xamarin.android

This is my code:

```
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        public ISharedFunctions SharedFunctions => DependencyService.Get<ISharedFunctions>();
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {        
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
           
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
           
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            // Add custom implementation, as needed.
            SharedFunctions.SaveFirebaseDeviceToken(token);
            SharedFunctions.GetFirebaseDeviceToken();

        }
    }
```

But  i get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'You must call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); prior to using this property.'
```

How to save it with DependencyService , because i use same Shared Function for save and get the token in Android and IOS?

Comment: you usually use DependencyService to access your platform code from your shared code.  You should not need it to access shared code from the platform project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use DependencyService to send data from platform project to shared project.

I would recommend you to use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send the data:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "Hi");
```

And in shared project:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) =>
{
    // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
});
```

If you want to get/save some data in Xamarin.forms, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)
:

Save the value with key:

```
Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");
```

Get the value with key:

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");
```

Comment: @Jacck Hua - MSFT i need to save the Firebase Device Token for both Android and IOS.

Comment: You can use Preferences to save with different key, what's your question?

Comment: I made it with MessagingCenter. Is it okay to call MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "Hi"); from both IOS and Android projects?

Comment: Sure, you can use MessagingCenter in both iOS and Android project.

Comment: MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,string>(this, "FirebaseToken", (args, list) =>
            {
                DependencyService.Get<ISharedFunctions>().SaveFirebaseDeviceToken(list);
         
            });